# Offline encyclopedia for Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

My question is concerning the latest LTS version of Ubuntu, not any of its offspring, e.g. Edubuntu, Lubuntu. I'm wondering if there is ANY way to get an offline Wikipedia on it. I work at the library in an offline situation and must have it downloaded onto the system.

I am familiar with both Kiwix and Xowa, and have ran them both offline on mac and windows, respectively. 
- I have seen that Sugar linux and Archlinux offer packages for Kiwix. But has anybody been able to successfully put Kiwix onto Ubuntu?
- I had tried to install Xowa on an older version of Ubuntu (real old... 10.4 on a Power PC mac), but couldn't get Xowa on it. I am debating installing the most recent version of Ubuntu on a newer computer, but don't want to bother if I won't be able to get some version of offline wikipedia on it.

Thanks for any helpful pointers,
Kara

Comment: Might be a good starting point ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: @dufte Good point on that, I've looked at that article before, but I had neglected to notice that there's a third option which works for Linux ... Aard2. Hadn't tried that. Worth a shot if Xowa doesn't work on 16.04.

Comment: You can try to donwload the GNU/Linux version of Kiwix from the official page: http://www.kiwix.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have java installed on your system.If you don't have it, download it using this command line:  `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

Now download the approprite XOWA version from [here](http://xowa.org/home/wiki/Help/Download_XOWA.html).

Then unzip it using the command(assuming that you have downloaded the 64bit version):`unzip xowa_linux_64.jar`

And then run it with command(assuming that you have downloaded the 64bit version):`sh xowa_linux_64.sh`

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an application solution, but www.archive.org has plenty of EPUB, and PDF encyclopedias. It may be worth your while to download and own some of them, if you were looking for something. Although it may not contain media, and quick links as Encyclopedia Britannica and other alternatives.